# What is a word for aroma, but for sight not smell

Tags: single-word-requests

Please, help me, I cannot think of the word..... I know it is something similar to aroma, but I cannot think of anything but aroma

Example: "The room gave off a warm and pleasant ___. John could smell a vanilla and lavender aroma in the air."

I was looking for the word *ambience*. I wasn't sure how else to describe it besides with sight. I realize that I was looking more for a word that helped describe the feel of the room, not how it looked. I apologize for any irritations I have caused. This is my first time using this site...

Comment: I realized just now that the word is aura or vibe. I apologize.

Comment: *Ambience* would fit reasonably well here, but it doesn't connote anything specific to sight. The example sentence doesn't connote much about sight either, and could be referring to the room's general character rather than specifically how it looks

Comment: Thank you, @Nuclear Hoagie That's the exact word I was looking for

Comment: I don't get how you want a 'sight' answer when the room's properties are described in olefactory terms. Why don't *aroma* or *scent* work?

Comment: Are you describing the *light* in the room, or the arrangement and appearance of the objects within it?

Comment: Since this looks like you are writing these sentences, we have to make sure the collocations are right. "The room -gave off- an aroma" but 'The room -had- an ambiance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Ambience***

> The ambience of a place is the character and atmosphere that it seems to have.
> [literary]
>
> - The overall ***ambience*** of the room is cosy. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ambience))

I would also go for ***feel***, it also matches your sentence:

> The ***feel*** of something, for example a place, is the general impression that it gives you.
>
> - The room has a warm, cosy feel. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/feel))

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user483173 Ambience refers to the general character of a setting, not exclusively how it looks. The ambience of a room is determined not only by how it looks, but how it smells, sounds, who's in it, what's happening in it, etc.